highlight the entire line in listview along with the image
There is a listview with the following settings and content:
ListView2.Columns.Add("First name")
ListView2.Columns.Add("Email")
ListView2.Columns.Add("Country")
ListView2.View = View.Tile
ListView2.FullRowSelect = True
ListView2.MultiSelect = False
ListView2.TileSize = New Size(250, 42)

Dim people = {
    New With {
            Key .FirstName = "FirstName",
            Key .Email = "firstname@emal.com",
            Key .Country = "USA"
            },
    New With {
            Key .FirstName = "FirstName1",
            Key .Email = "firstname1@emal.com",
            Key .Country = "USA"
            }
}
For Each person In people
    ListView2.AddRow(0, person.FirstName, person.Email, person.Country)
Next person

How can I make it so that when I click on a line (Item), the picture will also be highlighted?


Might be easier to use a DataGridView, styled to look like the ListView. The DGV has full row selection.

Try the explorer style.
